# Has anyone ported the Yesod chat-example to websockets?

Tags: websocket, yesod

Has anyone ported the Yesod chat-example to websockets?

http://www.yesodweb.com/book/wiki-chat-example

https://github.com/yesodweb/wai/blob/master/wai-websockets/Network/Wai/Handler/WebSockets.hs